# How to display Laravel Relationship data in a Blade View, when using groupBy() in query

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm making and inventory system for basic parts, that provides coverage for more than one company location. So my `inventory` table has parts information such as part_number and description as well as a `location_id` that foreign keys into a `locations` table. I have several stock items with the same part number, but have varying inventory levels at each location. I want to group the inventory by location, and then list all of the inventory at that location before cycling through the other locations and doing the same thing.

Here is what I have in my controller:

```
$inventory = Inventory::where('part_number', '12345')->get();

    // dd($inventory);

$inventory_grouped_by_location = $inventory->groupBy('location_id');

    // dd($inventory_grouped_by_location);

return view('inventory.show', compact('inventory_grouped_by_location');
```

Here is what I have in my Inventory model:

```
public function location()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Location::class);
}
```

Here is what I have in my Location model:

```
public function parts_inventory()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Inventory::class);
}
```

Here is what I have tried in my view:

```
@foreach($inventory_grouped_by_location as $location)

<p>Location: {{ $location->name }}</p>

    @foreach($location as $inventory)

        <p>Part Number: {{ $inventory->part_number }}</p>

    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

The above code throws and error because I'm trying to access the location relationship, but I've only got the `location->id` from the inventory table. I've tried to access the relationship like this `$location[$key]->name` but no joy.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, replace this query

```
$inventory_grouped_by_location = $inventory->groupBy('location_id');
```

with this

```
$inventory_grouped_by_location = Inventory::where('part_number', '12345')->with('location')->groupBy('location_id')->get();
```

In your blade, you can do something like this:

```
@foreach($inventory_grouped_by_location as $inventory)

<p>Location: {{ $inventory->location->name }}</p>

    <p>Part Number: {{ $inventory->part_number }}</p>

@endforeach
```

You can't loop through `$inventory` again since you already are at an index of the collection `$inventory_grouped_by_location`.

---

If you are looking to make the nested loop as specified in your question, you probably don't need `groupBy()` at all.

In your controller method:

```
$locations = Location::all();
$inventory = Inventory::where('part_number', 123456)->get();
```

And in your blade:

```
@foreach($locations as $location)

<p>Location: {{ $location->name }}</p>

    @foreach($inventory as $item)
        @if($item->location_id == $location->id)
        <p>Part Number: {{ $item->part_number }}</p>
        @endif
    @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Hope it helps!